# TinyMCE - Setting up for EE tags

Tags: tinymce, expressionengine

I've got a TinyMCE plugin that I'm using in Expression Engine. Problem is though I'm going from a textarea with code that uses EE tags to this and when saving it's breaking code.

For example, for an image I'll use `src="{site_url}/image/logo.png",` TinyMCE then rips out or corrupts the `{site_url}` part and try to and replace it with a relative path which (as site_url isn't at the root) is wrong.

I know you can add new tags for TinyMCE to respect in the config but this only assumes those wrapped in **<>** and not **{}**.

Anyone know if I can adapt this? Or have a better solution of something that will respect it?

Answer (score 2):

Since TineMCE is a wysiwyg you need the full image path in order for the TinyMCE to render the image. I would recommend backing up the database and then running a find replace and replace on the old paths via sql: http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/find-replace.html